# How to make side scroll bars appear when I scroll on all applications? For example on NYT, and Globe and Mail apps, scroll bar never appears

Tags: user-interface

My understanding is that Android makes the scroll bar appear on the right side of the screen only when you're scrolling, so you have an idea where you are in page.

For example if I go to my Settings app, when I scroll, a grey scroll bar appears to the right of the window, indicating to me where I am on the page, and how long the page is. (See screenshot.)

However, on the New York Times app, such a scroll never appears on my phone, making it impossible to know where I am in an article.

I thought this was a bug with the New York Times app, but I now realize that the Globe and Mail app is the same. The Guardian app, on the other hand, does show a scrollbar.

Is there a way I can reinstate (through some Android setting) the scrollbar, or does the problem lay with the apps themselves (NYT and Globe and Mail), in which case I will open a bug report with each of the apps. I find the latter unlikely, as it is highly annoying to have no indication of where you are in relation to a full article, and an online search yields no reference to this bug related the apps themselves.

I am using a Galaxy A9 with Android 10 and "One UI version" 2.5, with versions 9.77.0 of the NYTimes app and 7.5 of the Globe and Mail app.

[image]

Comment: Most likely those apps that don't have a scroll bar don't show their content in the native Android UI, instead the use a WebView, a web browser element shown by the app. According to some entries on Stackoverflow.com it seems like scroll bars in a WebView are disabled by default and you explicitly add code to enable them. So may be you should contact the NYT and give feedback how they could enhance their app.